# php / javascript - last character in string is never removed

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='username' onkeyup='findUsers(this.value)'>
<input type='submit' value='Add Member'>
<div id='livesearch'></div>
```

```js
<script>
 function findUsers(str) {
  if (str == "") {
   return;
  } else {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET","/classes/livemembersearch.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
 }
</script>
```

```html
$q = $_GET["q"];
```

When getting the value in the findUsers function, everything works fine, except when I empty the textfield, it keeps showing the last value before I emptied the field.

Examples:

1. I type "ffff", it updates, I remove one f at a time, it keeps
   updating, until I remove the last f and get an empty field, it just
   keeps showing an f as value passed.
2. I type "hello", it updates, when I remove the entire string at once,
   the value passed stays at hello.

I think the function is just not being called when the field is empty.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the function that is supposed to empty the textfield, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state within your function:

```
if (str == "") {
            return;
        }
```

This means the function won't complete and the issue you're presenting will indeed happen. I assume you're emptying the livesearch element?
Since `document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` is to be found in the `else` statement, it will never be executed.
Then it should be this:

```
if (str == "") {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
}
```

while leaving the rest as is.
So you empty it when `str` is empty, but you fill it when the ajax call is made.

p.s. the `return;` statement within the if statement is redundant. Since the if statement rings true, the else won't be executed either way.

**edit:** Also note that `onkeyup` might not trigger on someone copying text in instead of typing it. Although it's unlikely with a username, I thought it'd be a good thing to let you know, just in case.
-- the one that does catch this would be the `oninput` function.

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)

Comment: Thx!! Overlooked that, first time working with javascript.
What would you suggest to use instead of onkeyup?

Comment: `oninput` =) If my answer is to your satisfaction, please don't forget to accept it so people know the matter has been closed :)